# Error during auto-completion cache update: Access denied

Tags: mysql-shell

I'm trying the MySQL Shell for Windows.  First time using this.

I got as far as `\c` to connect, `\sql` to allow the familiar MySQL language, and a successful `show databases;`

When I attempted to `use mydata;` it threw this:

```
Fetching global names, object names from `mydata` for auto-completion... Press ^C to stop.
Error during auto-completion cache update: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the PROCESS privilege(s) for this operation
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to MySQL documentation, the `PROCESS` privilege is a server administrative feature that allows access to threads of all users.  A user granted `ALL` on a single database would not have this privilege.

One way to avoid the error is to disable auto-completion within the Shell by using this command first:

`shell.options['autocomplete.nameCache']=false`

After that, the `use` command is successful.

Documentation: [Configuring Autocompletion](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-autocompletion.html#mysql-shell-configuring-autocompletion)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).